# Colour scale HP Bar colors?

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I am attempting to use Color scale between two cells. The Right Cell is the maximum of the character's Hit points and the Left cell is their current Hit Points. I want it to scale between Red for less than 10%, Yellow if less than 65% and Green at 100%

But using the scale it shows as just Red to Yellow and then Pops in at full green value OR just stays red until it is 100% instead of scaling

[image: HP Bar]

[image: Condition Information]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need a couple of (v. simple!) formulae:

[image: SO54912815 example]

Midpoint has been truncated and is actually:

```
=C$1*0.65
```

Change Minpoint from `0` to `=C$1*0.1` if you prefer, but seems not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

use **`Number`** instead of **`Percentile`** where:

- min: `=C$1*0.1`
- mid: `=C$1*0.65`
- max: `=C$1`

[image]

Comment: I just need it to scale the value of the left cell to the value of the right... is there no way to do that? Cause the left cell is their current HP and right is their MAX HP so i would've like for it to work. If not I can do it in the program we are using to run the game but...

Comment: The problem being their HP doesn't stop at 100. They "can" have 3000 HP

Which is why I was trying to get it percent/percentile based